# R : Output of the command y[1]:y[3]

Tags: r

I have the vector :

```
 y=c(3,7,6,-1,2,4,7,5)
```

when i run the code

```
y[1]:y[3]
```

I get the output :

```
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

But i am not understanding what is the meaning of the code `y[1]:y[3]` and its output .

I got it when i was trying to get the first three observations of `y` vector . I know now to get the first three observations , the command is `y[1:3]` .

But what does `y[1]:y[3]` mean ? And where does the result come from ?

Comment: `y[1]` gives you 3 while `y[3]` returns 6. so `y[1]:y[3]` is the sequence from 3 to 6, i.e. 3,4,5,6. See `?":"` The reason you are getting different results is because in `y[1:3]`, `1:3` is being evaluated first, while in `y[1]:y[3]` ,  `y[1]` and `y[3]` are being evaluated first, e.g. what really happens is `":"(y[1], y[3])` and R evaluates functions from inside out.

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, as it seems that it could be useful for new useRs to understand how R works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y[1]` returns 3

```
y[1]
## [1] 3
```

while `y[3]` returns 6.

```
y[3]
## [1] 6
```

So `y[1]:y[3]` is the sequence from 3 to 6, i.e.

```
3:6
## [1] 3 4 5 6
```

See `?":"`

The reason you are getting different results is because in `y[1:3]`, `1:3` is being evaluated first, while in `y[1]:y[3]` , `y[1]` and `y[3]` are being evaluated first, e.g. what really happens is

```
`:`(y[1], y[3])
## [1] 3 4 5 6
```

and R evaluates functions from inside out, take this simple example for illustration

```
sd(mean(1:10))
## [1] NA
mean(sd(1:10))
## [1] 3.02765
```